# Delete rows above headers in a CSV using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I need to clean up a files using Pandas.  But the raw files we are using have a couple of rows above the column headers that I need to erase before getting to work.  I do not find how to get rid of them.

I suppose this has to be done before generating the frame.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

[Sample CSV raw file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbi3f.png)

Comment: create dataframe by using skiprows paramter of read_csv method of pandas, then do your processing and save file by using  pd.to_csv()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `skiprows` parameter in `read_csv()` :

```py
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows=5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It does work but it ignores the title row.

Comment: It woked!  Skip and then manually inserted column names.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to read it and happy to help ! Maybe you can try to set the `skiprows=5` to `skiprows=6` to get directly the header you want.